# Numpy is installed and has been running but suddenly I get missing module error despite reinstalling anaconda and purging numpy before re-installation

Tags: python, numpy, ubuntu-18.04

I was using numpy in a simple python script that calls and runs another program in a loop. It was working just fine for several days, then I needed to go somewhere so I tried to cancel the process, I was lazy and ended up just closing the terminal. The next time I tried to run it I started getting the following error:

### (base) cb27g11@cb27g11-Precision-7510:~/Development/Ciara$ sudo ipython3 Test_script.py

ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
/home/cb27g11/Development/Ciara/Test_script.py in ()
1 import subprocess
2 import fileinput
----> 3 import numpy as np
4
5 tan_beta = [20, 25, 30, 35, 40] #Array of tan(beta) values

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy'

But numpy is definitely still installed. I use anaconda and numpy is in the files for that. If I start a shell in the terminal and import numpy there's no problem, and "which python" returns:

`/home/cb27g11/anaconda3/bin/python`

So it seems as though the path is intact.

I've tried completely uninstalling numpy and anaconda, purging my computer of any files related to numpy and then reinstalling both to no success.

I then installed numpy via pip3 and I've been trawling through environment and anaconda files to see if theres a broken path but I'm struggling to find anything to fix this.

Just in case there's something wrong with my little script I'll add it below :

````
import fileinput
import numpy as np

tan_beta = [20, 25, 30, 35, 40] #Array of tan(beta) values
sin_bma = np.linspace(0.9, 1.1, 22)#Array of sin(beta-alpha) values
hcm =  250 # Mass of charged Higgses in GeV
textfilepath = '/home/cb27g11/models/mg_run.txt' #path to txt file madgraph will use
Process = 'AD_noCharge'

def the_main_event():
    with open('/home/cb27g11/Development/Ciara/mg_run_basic.txt','r') as old_card:
        text =old_card.read() #stores string of old_card ready for editing
    for i in range(0, len(tan_beta)):
        tb = tan_beta[i] # loops over tan(beta) values
        for j in range(0, len(sin_bma)):
            sbma = sin_bma[j] # loops over sin(beta-alpha) values
            make_input(tb, sbma, hcm, text)
            run_madgraph()

def make_input(Tb, Sbma, Hcm, Text):
# inputs are the value of tan_beta, the value of sin(beta-alpha) values, the desired mass for the charged higgses and a string of text

    with open(textfilepath, 'w') as new_card:
    #simulation card, the .txt file that gets fed to madgraph
        sim_card = Text.replace('TBV', str(Tb))
        sim_card = sim_card.replace('SBMAV', str(Sbma))
        sim_card = sim_card.replace('HCMV', str(Hcm))
        sim_card = sim_card.replace('NAME', str(Process)+'_' + str(Tb) +'_' + str(Sbma))
        new_card.write(sim_card) # saves new txt file for madgraph in ~/models (as this is linked to docker as an input)
    

def run_madgraph():
# starts madgraph in docker with a volume type output linked to $HOME/output on laptop and mount type input linked to $HOME/models, then tells it to run mg5_aMC using mg_run.txt as a file for it. 
    subprocess.run('sudo docker run -t -i -v $HOME/outputs:/var/MG_outputs --mount type=bind,source=$HOME/models,target=/app hfukuda/madgraph /home/hep/MG5_aMC_v2_6_3_2/bin/mg5_aMC /app/mg_run.txt', shell=True)

the_main_event()```
````

Comment: You run python as `sudo ipython3`, get an error and then check which python you are running with `which python`? What is the output of `sudo which ipython3`? Does `import numpy` work when running `python`?

Comment: I think you must have been onto something, it works when I remove the sudo part and just enter `ipython3 Test_Script.py` it runs fine. I don't understand why though, could you explain it to me?

Comment: Sudo runs the command as root user. The root user has a different working environment (e.g. different search PATH for commands). If anaconda is installed for your user, the root user does not know that, so it uses its own `ipython3` version, in which numpy is not installed. If you need root permissions, give `sudo` the full path to your users' `ipython3` (obtained via `which ipython3`). It might look something like `sudo /home/ciara/anaconda3/bin/ipython3 [FILENAME]`.

Comment: I see, thank-you for the clear explanation!